# React Redux Multi user registration

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working in a project, where it has four different users login and registration and their dashboard. I have a created the login part for all the user as it is an single API, i used switch case to redirect the user to dashboard based on the user type. I redux and axios in this process

Now, i need to create the registration part for them. For registration each user have different APIs. I have created a registration part and redux store for one user. So, for the remaining user, do, i need to create another store or i can do it in the same store itself.

Below is my register form code

Note: the form that i used below is just for an example. My original from has lot fields.

Thanks in Advance

```
/***Form One***/
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
 TextField } from '@material-ui/core';


class FormOne extends Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
email: "",
password: "",
confirmPassword: ""
};
}
buttonClick = event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.state);
             this.setState({
                 submitted: true
             })
             const {email, password} = this.state;

             const { dispatch } = this.props;
             if(email && password) {
                dispatch(registerUser(email, password))
             }
        }
render(){

return(
<div>
<TextField
                                id="standard-email-input"
                                label="Email"
                                className="form-field"
                                type="email"
                                name="email"
                                autoComplete="email"
                                onChange={this.props.email}
                            />
                            <TextField
                                id="standard-password-input"
                                label="Password"
                                className="form-field"
                                type="password"
                                name="password"
                                onChange={this.props.password}
                            />

                            <TextField
                                id="standard-confirm-input"
                                label="Confirm Password"
                                className="form-field"
                                type="password"
                                onChange={this.props.confirmPassword}
                                name="confirmPassword"
                            />
<Button variant="contained" className={classes.submitButton} onClick={this.buttonClick}>
                        Register Now
                    </Button>
</div>
)}
}

export default FormOne;

/***Form Two***/

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
 TextField } from '@material-ui/core';


class FormTwo extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
email: "",
password: "",
confirmPassword: ""
};
}
buttonClick = event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.state);
             this.setState({
                 submitted: true
             })
             const {email, password} = this.state;

             const { dispatch } = this.props;
             if(email && password) {
                dispatch(registerUser(email, password))
             }
        }
render(){

return(
<div>

<TextField
                                id="standard-email-input"
                                label="Email"
                                className="form-field"
                                type="email"
                                name="email"
                                autoComplete="email"
                                onChange={this.props.email}
                            />
                            <TextField
                                id="standard-password-input"
                                label="Password"
                                className="form-field"
                                type="password"
                                name="password"
                                onChange={this.props.password}
                            />

                            <TextField
                                id="standard-confirm-input"
                                label="Confirm Password"
                                className="form-field"
                                type="password"
                                onChange={this.props.confirmPassword}
                                name="confirmPassword"
                            />
<Button variant="contained" className={classes.submitButton} onClick={this.buttonClick}>
                        Register Now
                    </Button>
</div>
)}
}

export default FormTwo;

/***action.js***/

import axios from "axios";
import { REGISTERATION_REQUEST, REGISTERATION_COMPLETED, REGISTERATION_ERROR } from "./types";
import qs from "qs";
import history from '../../history/history.js';

const startRegister = () => {
    return {
      type: REGISTERATION_REQUEST
    };
  };

  const registerComplete = data => ({
    type: REGISTERATION_COMPLETED,
    data
  });

  const registerError = err => ({
    type: REGISTERATION_ERROR,
    err
  });


  export const registerUser = (email, password) => {
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch(startRegister());

      let headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      };

      const data = qs.stringify({
        email, password
      });

      axios
      .post("api-link/registerUserOne", data, {
        headers: headers
      })
      .then(function (resp) {

        dispatch(registerComplete());
        window.location.reload();
        history.push('/login');
        //dispatch(registerComplete(resp.data));

      })
      .catch(err => dispatch(registerError(err)));
    }


  };

/**reducer.js***/
import { REGISTERATION_REQUEST, REGISTERATION_COMPLETED, REGISTERATION_ERROR } from "./types";
import initialState from "./initialState";

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REGISTERATION_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        token: null,
        userName: ""
      };

    case REGISTERATION_COMPLETED:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.data.access_token,
        userName: action.data.userName,
        userType: action.data.userType
      };

    case REGISTERATION_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: true,
        people: []
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;

/***initialState.js***/
const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    token: null,
    userName: "",
    userType: null
  };

  export default initialState;


/***Type.js***/
const REGISTERATION_REQUEST = "REGISTERATION_REQUEST";
const REGISTERATION_COMPLETED = "REGISTERATION_COMPLETED";
const REGISTERATION_ERROR = "REGISTERATION_ERROR";

export { REGISTERATION_REQUEST, REGISTERATION_COMPLETED, REGISTERATION_ERROR };

/***index.js(reducer)***/
import reducer from "./reducer";
export default reducer;
```

Comment: I assume you have something related to roles for each user, you can use the same registration form for each one but just have something like a select to identify the role. We also need to see some code in order to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are asking about quite open scenario that can be solved to many ways. Are you going to use the same form for all users? Is the api call the main difference between users or there is something more?

Comment: I have created different form for each user, as it have different fields for each user.

Comment: I added my code in the above post @NicolaeMaties

Comment: I don't get how you are differentiating which user gets which form,  you have to make that decision based on a user input.